# How to use Blazor WASM gradually as part of existing Asp.Net Core Angular project

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have an application with Asp.Net core back-end and Angular front-end I want to convert the front-end part of it to Blazor WASM because it is very big I need to convert the frontend part of it gradually now my question is,Is there any way to use Blazor WASM component in Asp.Net Angular project or even further is there any way to use Blazor component inside an Angular component?

Comment: I think you could  refer to [this article](https://www.thinktecture.com/en/blazor/integration-angular-elements-web-components/).

Comment: Thanks for the response @Rena but this article explains the opposite of what I want. I have an Asp.net Angular application I want to setup Blazor Wasm into that application and gradually replace angular components with Blazor components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to make the Blazor component(s) available for instantiation from JavaScript by calling [`JSComponentConfigurationExtensions.RegisterForJavaScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.jscomponentconfigurationextensions.registerforjavascript), which is available from ASP.NET Core 6.0 on.

Bridging the gap from a Blazor component to an Angular component requires some further steps. The [JavaScript Component Generation](https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/main/samples/aspnetcore/blazor/JSComponentGeneration) sample from the ASP.NET samples shows one possible solution.

Based on this code, I've created a demo project [BlazorInAngularDemo](https://github.com/Xenoage/BlazorInAngularDemo) including an automated build process (see [demo](https://xenoage.github.io/BlazorInAngularDemo/#/) deployed to github pages).